# what is the difference between a unified data warehouse and a unified data model?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

I ask as the words are used pretty much interchangeably in some documentation I have had to review.

In the real world what are the differences?

Comment: Data Warehouse is a much bigger concept. Besides data model, DW contains control flow system, security management, platform adminstration, ETL process, meta-data, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A "Data Warehouse" is mostly an information systems concept that describes a centralized and trusted source of (e.g. company/business) data.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse): "DWs are central repositories of integrated data from one or more disparate sources. They store current and historical data in one single place that are used for creating analytical reports for workers throughout the enterprise."

That being said, I think it's a bit redundant to say "unified data warehouse"; a data warehouse is a "unified" source of data by definition.

This definition implies that the data model in a data warehouse must/should be a unified, canonical model of all relevant data. You can also look at a Data Warehouse as a collection of data marts, which in turn are smaller unified/canonical models focused on specific business/functional areas; so the "unified data model" is can be thought of as the sum of the various smaller/specific models (the data marts).

A Data Warehouse, as an information system, is usually surrounded by a lot of technology tools (databases, ETL software, analytics and reporting tools, etc); but regardless of how you handle, model and explore data, the primary purpose of a DW is to serve as a curated, single source of truth for (business) questions that (should) rely on data.